# Built in forEach utility in Angular v2-6 like in AnularJS

Tags: angular

Is there in Angular v2-6 a build in forEach method like in AngularJS, see [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) of angularJS `angular.forEach(obj, iterator, [context]);`.

I like that function in angularJS because it works on arrays as well as on objects (forEach is iterating over the object properties in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular doesn't contain helpers like AngularJS, this isn't framework's responsibility to provide a user with generic-purpose helper methods. This was reasonable at that moment but isn't useful in modern JS development.

This is totally achievable with native methods. Arrays and other iterators are supposed to be iterated with `for..of`:

```
for (const val of iterator) {...}
```

Objects can be iterated as well:

```
for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {...}
```

If you are sure that native methods don't provide the functionality you need, you can always import a library like Lodash and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You you have `Array.forEach()`. Isnt that enough?

Comment: Sure, but that is only suited for Arrays and not for object properties. Ofcourse iterating over object properties isn't a big deal, but I was looking for a common method to do so, since there was a method suited for both usecases in AngularJS.

Comment: You could use `Object.entries()` to have a key/value iterable array.

Comment: You have `Object.keys` to get all object keys and iterate

Answer (score 0):

In the template there is only `*ngFor` built-in. However, you can build your own structural directive that can handle both. In the .ts-code you can use

`Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => console.log(key));` and `Array.forEach()`. For using both together you can as well build an own function.